# Is necessary to create a new table in this context?

Tags: database-design

I have a table Template and another ProjectDescriptions. A template can have many ProjectDescriptions, so the tables are like this:

```
Template: id, title, etc
ProjectDescriptio: title, description, template_id, etc
```

In the backoffice there is a screen for the user to create new project descriptions for a specific template.

In the frontend there is a list that shows the project descriptions for a specific template. There is a combobox for the user to select the project description that he wants, the can associate more than one project description to a template. My doubt is how to store the selected project descriptions. Is necessary to create a new table?

Comment: Template entity instance and project entity instance generated based on a template are two separate non-related entities instances, they must be NOT related. So when the user edits some attributes of the project instance this does not effect on template instance or another project instance. Moreover, I do not see the reason to store the info what template was used for to create project instance (but this may be stored in some additional column as a note).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the same `ProjectDescription` can be used by multiple different `Templates` then you'll need a third table, as a linking table, for the **many-to-many** relationship between the two entities. Otherwise you'd be forced to store duplicate rows in `ProjectDescription` which is bad design from a [**Normalization**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/database-normalization-description) standpoint.

The linking table would be simple and just store `template_id` and `projectdescription_id`, and the **primary key** would be a composite key on both those fields.